# Transacting with a verified contract (code+ABI); yet, no function displayed in the tx input data

Tags: transactions, abi, contract-verification

Looking at the transaction overview in etherscan, the "Input Data:" field is only a big Hex value; I was expecting to see the function I was calling...

Comment: How exactly do you expect anyone to refer to your question here??? Please post the minimum required for readers to understand your input, output and problem.

Comment: Ok. I was interacting with this DDEX contract : 0x241e82C79452F51fbfc89Fac6d912e021dB1a3B7. This contract is labelled as "verified" by etherscan, so I was expecting to read the function I was calling when interacting with the DDEX website. Still, the "Input Data" section of the transaction in etherscan only prints the following Hex string: "0x8059cf3b0..006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de6d88ea00e2030000". How is that possible for etherscan not to recognize the function that was called? Is that a limitation of etherscan?

Comment: Why not simply post the link here?

Comment: Anonymity??? I can see it [here (block 9141403)](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa16946a605ddb755d3a5774b6124f97fed1bd1e3). No point hiding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode it programmatically with web3.js (tested with version 1.2.1):

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io");
const addr = "0x241e82c79452f51fbfc89fac6d912e021db1a3b7";
const abi  = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"delegate","type":"address"}],"name":"approveDelegate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"orderHash","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"isOrderCancelled","outputs":[{"name":"isCancelled","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"user","type":"address"},{"name":"marketID","type":"uint16"}],"name":"isAccountLiquidatable","outputs":[{"name":"isLiquidatable","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"asset","type":"address"}],"name":"getPoolCashableAmount","outputs":[{"name":"cashableAmount","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"marketID","type":"uint16"}],"name":"getMarket","outputs":[{"components":[{"name":"baseAsset","type":"address"},{"name":"quoteAsset","type":"address"},{"name":"liquidateRate","type":"uint256"},{"name":"withdrawRate","type":"uint256"},{"name":"auctionRatioStart","type":"uint256"},{"name":"auctionRatioPerBlock","type":"uint256"},{"name":"borrowEnable","type":"bool"}],"name":"market","type":"tuple"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"user","type":"address"},{"name":"marketID","type":"uint16"}],"name":"liquidateAccount","outputs":[{"name":"hasAuction","type":"bool"},{"name":"auctionID","type":"uint32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"marketID","type":"uint16"},{"name":"asset","type":"address"},{"name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"getMarketTransferableAmount","outputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"marketID","type":"uint16"},{"name":"newAuctionRatioStart","type":"uint256"},{"name":"newAuctionRatioPerBlock","type":"uint256"},{"name":"newLiquidateRate","type":"uint256"},{"name":"newWithdrawRate","type":"uint256"}],"name":"updateMarket","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"auctionID","type":"uint32"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"fillAuctionWithAmount","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"auctionID","type":"uint32"}],"name":"getAuctionDetails","outputs":[{"components":[{"name":"borrower","type":"address"},{"name":"marketID","type":"uint16"},{"name":"debtAsset","type":"address"},{"name":"collateralAsset","type":"address"},{"name":"leftDebtAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"leftCollateralAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"ratio","type":"uint256"},{"name":"price","type":"uint256"},{"name":"finished","type":"bool"}],"name":"details","type":"tuple"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"assetAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"getAsset","outputs":[{"components":[{"name":"lendingPoolToken","type":"address"},{"name":"priceOracle","type":"address"},{"name":"interestModel","type":"address"}],"name":"asset","type":"tuple"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"asset","type":"address"},{"name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"getAmountSupplied","outputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getHydroTokenAddress","outputs":[{"name":"hydroTokenAddress","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"exitIncentiveSystem","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"asset","type":"address"},{"name":"oracleAddress","type":"address"},{"name":"interestModelAddress","type":"address"},{"name":"poolTokenName","type":"string"},{"name":"poolTokenSymbol","type":"string"},{"name":"poolTokenDecimals","type":"uint8"}],"name":"createAsset","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"relayer","type":"address"}],"name":"canMatchOrdersFrom","outputs":[{"name":"canMatch","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"asset","type":"address"},{"name":"extraBorrowAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getInterestRates","outputs":[{"name":"borrowInterestRate","type":"uint256"},{"name":"supplyInterestRate","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"getDiscountedRate","outputs":[{"name":"rate","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"user","type":"address"},{"name":"marketID","type":"uint16"}],"name":"getAccountDetails","outputs":[{"components":[{"name":"liquidatable","type":"bool"},{"name":"status","type":"uint8"},{"name":"debtsTotalUSDValue","type":"uint256"},{"name":"balancesTotalUSDValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"details","type":"tuple"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"orderHash","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"getOrderFilledAmount","outputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getCurrentAuctions","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint32[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"assetAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"getAssetOraclePrice","outputs":[{"name":"price","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"asset","type":"address"}],"name":"getInsuranceBalance","outputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"asset","type":"address"}],"name":"getTotalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"asset","type":"address"},{"name":"oracleAddress","type":"address"},{"name":"interestModelAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"updateAsset","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"hash","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"signerAddress","type":"address"},{"components":[{"name":"config","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"signature","type":"tuple"}],"name":"isValidSignature","outputs":[{"name":"isValid","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"components":[{"name":"actionType","type":"uint8"},{"name":"encodedParams","type":"bytes"}],"name":"actions","type":"tuple[]"}],"name":"batch","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"asset","type":"address"}],"name":"getTotalBorrow","outputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"components":[{"name":"baseAsset","type":"address"},{"name":"quoteAsset","type":"address"},{"name":"liquidateRate","type":"uint256"},{"name":"withdrawRate","type":"uint256"},{"name":"auctionRatioStart","type":"uint256"},{"name":"auctionRatioPerBlock","type":"uint256"},{"name":"borrowEnable","type":"bool"}],"name":"market","type":"tuple"}],"name":"createMarket","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"asset","type":"address"},{"name":"user","type":"address"},{"name":"marketID","type":"uint16"}],"name":"getAmountBorrowed","outputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"isOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"relayer","type":"address"}],"name":"isParticipant","outputs":[{"name":"result","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getAllMarketsCount","outputs":[{"name":"count","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"components":[{"components":[{"name":"trader","type":"address"},{"name":"baseAssetAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"quoteAssetAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"gasTokenAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"data","type":"bytes32"},{"components":[{"name":"config","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"signature","type":"tuple"}],"name":"takerOrderParam","type":"tuple"},{"components":[{"name":"trader","type":"address"},{"name":"baseAssetAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"quoteAssetAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"gasTokenAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"data","type":"bytes32"},{"components":[{"name":"config","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"signature","type":"tuple"}],"name":"makerOrderParams","type":"tuple[]"},{"name":"baseAssetFilledAmounts","type":"uint256[]"},{"components":[{"name":"baseAsset","type":"address"},{"name":"quoteAsset","type":"address"},{"name":"relayer","type":"address"}],"name":"orderAddressSet","type":"tuple"}],"name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"matchOrders","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newInitiatorRewardRatio","type":"uint256"}],"name":"updateAuctionInitiatorRewardRatio","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"asset","type":"address"}],"name":"getIndex","outputs":[{"name":"supplyIndex","type":"uint256"},{"name":"borrowIndex","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"components":[{"name":"trader","type":"address"},{"name":"relayer","type":"address"},{"name":"baseAsset","type":"address"},{"name":"quoteAsset","type":"address"},{"name":"baseAssetAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"quoteAssetAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"gasTokenAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"data","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"order","type":"tuple"}],"name":"cancelOrder","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"joinIncentiveSystem","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newInsuranceRatio","type":"uint256"}],"name":"updateInsuranceRatio","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newConfig","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"updateDiscountConfig","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"marketID","type":"uint16"},{"name":"usability","type":"bool"}],"name":"setMarketBorrowUsability","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getAuctionsCount","outputs":[{"name":"count","type":"uint32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"marketID","type":"uint16"},{"name":"asset","type":"address"},{"name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"marketBalanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"asset","type":"address"},{"name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"delegate","type":"address"}],"name":"revokeDelegate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_hotTokenAddress","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"}];
const data = "0x8059cf3b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de6d88ea00e2030000";
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, addr);
for (const object of contract._jsonInterface) {
    if (data.startsWith(object.signature)) {
        console.log("function name = " + object.name);
        console.log("function parameters:");
        console.log(web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(object.inputs, data.slice(object.signature.length)));
        break;
    }
}
```